# How to search String with "\" character and to Replace it

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, search, grep

I am Stuck into an issue regarding searching and replacing a directory path included in my thousands of file, what I want, to search those directory path in files and to replace it with new directory path -

For example - let a path is include in file is "var\www" which I want to replace with "var\www\html" which is written in my files in multiple files.

I tried grep command to search first -

`grep -rl "var\www" directory-path`

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come over the issue very soon - :)

below is the command which I tried and its successfully working to `Search and Replace Paths` written in multiple files in a directory -

`grep -rl 'var\\www' /your/path/to/directory/to/replace/content/in/files/ | xargs sed -i 's/var\\www/var\\www\\html/g'`

Where `var\www` is the written path in searched files which I replaced with `var\www\html`